# How to save the first three elements of a list without saving the whole list on memory

Tags: python, list

Here's my list :

```
result = [(a,f,4),(b,g,4),(c,h,6),(d,i,8),(e,j,10)]
```

To optimize my code, i want to save in result only the three first element, here's what I did :

```
for kword in keywords():
    result = []   
    first_words = []
    for word in words():
        similarity = similarity(keywords.get(kword), words.get(word))      
        result.append((kword, word, similarity))
    result.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
    for i in range(3):
        first_words.append(result[i][3])
```

I realize that by this I'm saving on memory result, and first_words. How can I save directly in result the three first elements ?

Comment: what is your input? and what do you mean by storing first 3 elements

Comment: I only want to save [(a,f,4),(b,g,4),(c,h,6)]. My input are kword, word and similarity

Comment: may be you are looking for this `first_words.append(result[i][:3])`. You are adding only 3rd element if you want first 3 elements use slice operation

Comment: Can you please show the hole function? As of now, it is not clear why you don't simply do `first_words = result[:3]`

Comment: The thing is, by this I'm already saving the list "result". After running this for over 200.000 words for exemple it may cause problem. My question is if there's a way to save in result the first three elements directly without having to save all of the elements on result and then create another list to save the three elements.

Comment: fisrt_words=result[0:3]

Comment: @Ma0 I can do that, but is there a way to save it directly on result ?

Comment: then do `result = result[:3]`. Note that all other entries will be lost in this case though since you are overwriting it

Answer (score 1):

You can return a the first three elements of your list with slicing:

```py
first_words = result[:3]
```

This would go through all items of `keywords()` and the first 3 items of `words()`:

```py
for kword in keywords():
    first_words = [(kword, word, similarity(keywords.get(kword), words.get(word)) for word in words()[:3]]
```

If you want to get the first 3 elements of the sorted list, you will need the whole list, otherwise the rest elements won't be included in the sort.

Comment: Is there a way to only save the three first elements on results[], since I don't need result to contain the whole 5 elements?

Comment: So you want to go through the first 3 items of keywords(), and words()? Or all keywords(), but only the first 3 items of words()?

Comment: And similarity. Here's what I need : result = [(a,f,4),(b,g,4),(c,h,6)] but here's what I end up saving in my result list : result = [(a,f,4),(b,g,4),(c,h,6),(d,i,8),(e,j,10)]. I don't need to save the whole five elements in my list but only the first three.

Comment: I edited my answer to go through all items of `keywords()` and the first 3 items of `words()`.